# Items does not sets disabled after first click on ListBox in Chrome

Tags: gwt

Here is my code:

```
listbox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                serv.getSlotStatusesStrings(clientFactory.getWorkspaceId(), new AsyncCallback<SlotStatusGwtStruct>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(SlotStatusGwtStruct result) {
                        List<String> statusList = Arrays.asList(result.styleName);
                        int emtyCounter = 0;
                        boolean passFlag = false;
                        boolean failFlag = false;
                        for(String status : statusList){
                            if(status.equals("empty")){
                                emtyCounter++;
                            }else if(status.equals("pass")){
                                passFlag = true;
                            }else if(status.equals("fail")){
                                failFlag = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if(emtyCounter == statusList.size()){
                            listbox.getElement().<SelectElement>cast().getOptions().getItem(0).setDisabled(true);
                        }
                        if(passFlag == false){
                            listbox.getElement().<SelectElement>cast().getOptions().getItem(1).setDisabled(true);
                        }
                        if(failFlag == false){
                            listbox.getElement().<SelectElement>cast().getOptions().getItem(2).setDisabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

In Firefox it works ok, but in Chrome browser when I click on listbox at the first time all my items are enabled (by condition they should be disabled), and after I made one more click I have the expected result.

Could yo please give me some advice how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure they are enabled _after_ the AsyncCallback is executed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Temporally I've resolved it by changing  addClickHandler() to addMouseOverHandler().